# Detect Textbox Field Change jQuery

Tags: javascript, text

I have a text box that accepts integers, and I need it to run a function that will use the text box's input, as soon as a user inputs numbers into the field.

The problem here is that `keyUp()` will detect each and every input. So if I type `23`, it will fire once for `2` and once for `3`. I only need it to run when the input is complete.

Is there a way to do this, without losing focus and without using a timer that will keep checking the text box input every while using `setInterval`?

Comment: how will you tell when the input is complete?

Comment: That's the thing. Can I install a timer only when the user starts to change the value and run that for 1500 ms? I have a setInterval brute forcing method now but that crashes the browser after running the page for a few minutes and doing stuff with it.

Comment: @Nayefc - instead of setInterval, use setTimeout, clearing the timeout on keydown and starting it on keyup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like you want to be notified when the user stops typing. The following code can be used as a starting point, it calls bufferedKeyUp 300 ms after the user stops typing. http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/VTMEe/

```
$(function() {
    // Creates a handler that will wait until the event hasn't fired for a period 
    // before it fires the actual event handler
    function createBuffered(fun, delay) {
        var timer;
        return function() {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            var args = arguments;
            var me = this;
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
               fun.apply(me, args);
            }, delay);        
        }
    }   

    $('#in').keyup( createBuffered(function(){
        console.log('change');
    }, 300));
});​
```

Ext-JS has a nice simple way to do this http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/DYkmU/1/

```
Ext.get('myid').on('keyup', function() {
  console.log('change');
}, null, {buffer: 300});
```

Comment: This keeps firing `bufferedKeyUp` and never stops, even when the user stops typing.

Comment: Funny.. When I change it to alert() it keeps getting called. I kept it as console.log now and just used a debugger and I guess it works.

Comment: This crashes my browser after I input 3 or 4 different things. Is this normal for `setTimeout`? A profiler shows that `setTimeout` takes most of the activity.

Comment: @Nayefc Please be more descriptive with your comments, it's hard to help when you don't provide enough information, post examples of something that (you say) is not working. None of your comments are actually doing what you say they are doing from my testing. Putting in `alert` instead of `console.log` doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'm sorry. This works properly I had other issues. There's one issue with this, however. Assume I enter `1`. This processes properly. However, to process the next input as a change, I need to highlight 1 and then re-enter a value. If I just click the textbox again and hit backspace and re-enter another value, it gets the old value processed one more time and considers it a change. How can I handle this?

Comment: @Nayefc: Again, I don't know what you mean. Typing 1, waiting (getting the event), then selecting everything, hitting backspace, typing 123, I only get the handler called after I typed 123, assuming I type backspace1234 fast enough. I never had it called with the wrong value. See how I created jsfiddles to show you? If you want to say something doesn't work, you should create a jsfiddle that we can both look at and talk about

Comment: I don't understand why you don't understand what I am saying. I am writing perfectly descriptive comments! I am using that same exact code. No need for JSFiddle! When I type `123`, and hit backspace to re-enter a new value, after each backspace it called the `createdBuffered` function. So typing `123`, and deleting it using backspace, it will go ahead and call `createdBuffered` with `12` and `1` in the textbox field. It calls it after EACH backspace hit.

Comment: @Nayefc: What you said happens only if you have delays of longer than 300ms between your backspaces, guaranteed. I'm just trying to help you, don't be a jerk with your comments! I think you still don't understand what createBuffered is doing...

Comment: @JuanMendes: why do you keep on insisting my comments are "bad"? You know it's pretty hard to explain stuff like that. It only takes reading over a sentence again to get it, if you didn't the first time. This is not an English forum, so its not really the best place to be particular about phrases. I do appreciate your efforts however, so yeah, you get the correct answer back.

Comment: I wasn't being a jerk - I thought you were. I'm sorry - you I gave you the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Nayfec: Your first comment was completely wrong... without any indication that you had actually tried my example. Then you said, "crashes my browser after I input 3 or 4 different things" without explaining it, than you said that typing backspace would cause the event to fire, but you left some time in between the backspaces. When I'm getting help, I make sure I'm very clear so that people taking their time to answer can readily help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test the textbox contents after they're changed, after all that's when input is complete isn't it?

If the result is not okay, you can always clear and focus the textbox so the user has to enter valid data.

Something like:

```
$("textbox").change( function () {
    if (someTestForGoodData) {
        handleTheGoodData();
    } else {
        $(this).focus();
        alert($(this) + " has bad data!");
    }
})
```

Comment: Because both: `2` and `23123` are "good" data. How can you differentiate?

Comment: Why would you differentiate? When the user is done typing, and the textbox sends a change event, whatever they've entered will be in the textbox and that's what you check. If it's 2 great, if it's 23123 still great.

Comment: The OP is not looking for the change event, that requires that the field lose focus

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that's the issue. I was looking at it as not losing focus if the data isn't okay (so I said to set focus back). I wasn't thinking of it as checking data without a change event. But is the user really going to use it that way?

Comment: It "sounds" simple, but isn't. I want a user to enter a number in a text box, and magically, without any losing focus or anything happening, some functions runs in the background. Without clicking a button, without losing focus. Without anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').on('input propertychange', function() {
    $('#output').html($(this).val().length + ' characters');
});
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349410/automatically-showing-changes-without-losing-focus) answer.