# Automatically showing changes without losing focus

Tags: jquery, focus

I currently have 2 divs that I have to click out of to show any % change.  Is there a way that I can adjust the code to show the % change without clicking out of the box?

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.originalData').change(function () {
        $('.changedData').val($(this).val());
        $('.percentage').text('0%');

    });
    $('.changedData').change(function () {
        var changedData = $(this).val().length;
        var originalData = $('.originalData').val().length;

        var percentageOfChange = changedData / originalData * 100 - 100
        $('.percentage').text(percentageOfChange.toFixed(2) + '%');
    });
});

<div class="content">
<p>Original:</p>
<textarea class='originalData'></textarea>  
<p>Changed:</p>
<textarea class='changedData'></textarea>
<div class='percentage'></div>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update where you use `.change` to use `.keyup`

Comment: I don't think it does, no. I just had a look online though after your question and [found this](http://jsfiddle.net/urEhK/59/) which seems to cater for pasted content although it seems the `propertychange` event is not  implemented by all browsers...